# How do I automatically terminate EC2 instances after a CFN update?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

So, I've created a stack with app version 1.0.0.0. Time for release so I update the parameters file with the new configs and via cli send the stack-update.

I can see the stack been updated and the autoscaling update complete. But I don't see the EC2s updating/terminating themselves.

I have my autoscaling set to 1/2/1; min/max/desired. What am I missing to automate this process? I really do not want to have to manually go into the console and terminate EC2 one by one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as CloudFormation is concerned, your infrastructure has been updated correctly. This is because you have **not changed any property on the Amazon EC2 instances** that would force an update.

There are various reports that the EC2 instances can be 'forced' to replace by **modifying something in the User Data** (eg a version number or using a parameter). This would trigger replacement of the instances when the stack is updated.

See:

- [7 Awesome CloudFormation Hacks](http://garbe.io/blog/2017/07/17/cloudformation-hacks/#hack-iii-changes-in-cfn-init-dont-trigger-redeployment-in-autoscaling-group)
- [How do I force a CloudFormation stack to update when the parameter is updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46826178/174777)
- [Is it possible to force Re-creation of EC2::Instance or RDS::DBInstance in amazon cloudformation?](https://serverfault.com/a/708690/267968)
- [AWS Developer Forums: Force replacement of ec2 instances in ...](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=696492)

Comment: ah, so there's no real automagic way. im working on my decvi environment, i guess i'll just have to shoot a few terminate commands... thanks for the resources